# set date picker to default date in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I have `GWT Date picker` (GWT Validating textbox) control on my `spring` web application. I want to restrict user for date selection such that the user registering to my system must be 16 years or older. Throughout google search the most solutions I found was using `jquery` which I don't want to use.

Can anyone suggest me how can I set the date range for selection?

Comment: It means the user must select current date to older 16 years.

Comment: Are you sure a calendar is the best widget to select a birth date? If I am 50 years old, I must click 50 times on "previous year" ???